# Searching an array with user input and printing all elements that have this value

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, java.util.scanner, traversal

I'm trying to search an array for a certain value and display all the elements which contain this value in java. For example, the user selects the number 5, there are 3 projects stored in the array with this value so all 3 of those will be printed out. My code is compiling ok, but when I run it, it jumps to the else statement, even if I am inputting a number that is in the array..
Any help would be amazing. Here's my code:

```
                case 3:
                //display all elements with the same state
                //get number user wishes to search for
                
                boolean found = false;
                 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                 System.out.print("Please enter the number you wish to search for");

                 //read user input
                 num = input.nextInt();

                 //traverse array
                 int k = 0;
                 for(k=0; k < myMonths.length; k++){
                     if(myMonths[index] == num){
                         found = true;
                         break;}
                     if(found){System.out.println(k);}

                     else{System.out.println("not found");}
                 }
                break;
```

Here's the array:

```
            //Menu loop
            int myMonths[] = new int[5];
            int index = 0;
            int num;
            while(choice !=6){


                switch (choice){
                case 1:
                //int n = number of projects
                int n = 1;
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("How many months was your project?");


                for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
                    int a = sc.nextInt();

                    //if months is lesser than 2/greater than 12
                    if((a < 2) || (a > 12)){
                        System.out.println("Please enter an amount between 2 and 12 months");}

                   //if months is between 2 and 12 add it to the array

                    else{myMonths[index++] = a;} }
                break;
```

Comment: `if(myMonths[index] == num){` should be `if(myMonths[k] == num){` -- pay attention to your variable names.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I've amended it but still the same problem, just jumps to the else statement and prints "not found" four times

Comment: Next bug: Don't check if it was found on every iteration of the loop. That should be **outside** the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm on the right track now. If I enter multiple numbers the same to the array, it only prints the index point of the first number entered. If possible, a hint on how to print the all would be great!

Comment: It wont let me attach a screenshot, but I added the number four twice to my array, then chose to display all elements with the value of 4, and it just printed '1' referring to the location of number 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using `k` instead of `index`. Second, you shouldn't be printing "not found" (or testing for that) on every iteration. You should limit variable scope as much as practical. And you also mention wanting to find all matching indices so you shouldn't terminate the loop prematurely; I think you wanted something like

```
//assume the value isn't present.
boolean found = false;
//read user input
int num = input.nextInt();

//traverse array
for(int k = 0; k < myMonths.length; k++) {
    if (myMonths[k] == num){
        found = true;
        System.out.println(k); // don't break or the loop ends early.
    }
}
//this test can only be done after you iterate **all** values.
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! That's solved it. And thanks for your explanations, it's much clearer in my mind now where & why I was going wrong